# How to emulate global aliases from zsh in bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

In `zsh`, you can define global aliases. For example,

```
alias -g G='| grep'
alias -g W='| wc -l'
```

and then use them like this:

```
some_command G some_text W
```

Can global aliases be somehow emulated in `bash`?

Comment: I believe you have to edit your ~/.bashrc file if you want to use aliases systemwide. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) is a question related to how to do it on Ubuntu, maybe you can adapt the answers to your system

Comment: @Ploutox 1) Here "global" means "on the whole command line not only as a first word. 2) As `~/.bashrc` resides in a user's home directory, it is *not* the place for systemwide settings.

Comment: @Adaephon for your second point, one could use /etc/bash.bashrc instead to apply settings systemwide. I should have written this path in the first place :)

Comment: You might be able to set up a `readline` macro to automatically expand `G` to `| grep` as you are typing, but that has the obvious drawback of preventing you from typing G for any other purpose. By the time you get a macro name distinct enough to prevent unwanted expansion, you're better off just typing `| grep`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you never want to use capital G for any other purpose, you could add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
bind '"G": "| grep"'
```

This will expand G to `| grep` as soon as you type it. That is, Shift+g no longer produces a capital G, but the string `| grep`. You'd want to choose a longer sequence that you would never expect to otherwise type, either by itself or as part of another word.

Comment: WHAT A | grepOOD IDEA!

Comment: LOL. It took me a while to understand @kojiro 's reply. But once I got it I was rofl

Comment: And, it only took 62 months for someone to (apparently) ignore my caveat and downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save it into a variable

```
g='| grep'
```

Then, your command could be

```
eval some_command $G some_text
```

OR

`some_command $G some_text` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (on other systems, it [seems to be](https://superuser.com/questions/215950/how-to-expand-on-bash-command-line) ?`ctrl+x+*` and is configurable)

which expands the command to the desired `some_command | grep some_text`, so you can then press Enter. Variables that should not be expanded would have to be in single quotes.

Nothing like zsh though.